# visual studio for mac auto add semicolon or hotkeys

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

How to don't type ";" after every line in c#, is there some hotkeys or auto addition a semicolon ?

I use visual studio community edition for mac
At windows solution is shift+enter or may be extensions like resharper

Comment: What? I mean... the `;` key is right next to the `enter` key?

Comment: What do you mean? ";" is present in all keyboards!!!

Comment: i don't want to put ; manually

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio for mac community and on top menu click on `Visual Studio Community` then click on `Preference`, from opened popup go to `Key Bindings`, in this part you can set hotkeys.

If you want see all default hotkey of visual studio mac, see https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Rider IDE is better way probably
there is complete current statement key